# Do I need to install Docker to install a gitlab-runner in windows?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Can't install gitlab-runner through windows. When running the command **gitlab-runner install**, I am getting this error-
    **The term 'gitlab-runner' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
    function, script file, or operable program.**

I configured gitlab-runner two times. First with docker as executor and also used docker for the image. And after that, I configured one with shell as executor. But both of the times I got the error when I am trying to install the runner.

**Do I need to install docker in my machine?** 
[I am totally new to CI. So, some helping hand will help me a lot.]

config.toml for docker

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
 session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "ababil-deposit-web-runner"
  url = "http://gitlab.mislbd.lan/"
  token = "b95494a9f59de1ea9bc9643a17fa8b"
  executor = "docker"
[runners.docker]
  tls_verify = false
  image = "docker"
  privileged = false
  disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
  oom_kill_disable = false
  disable_cache = false
  volumes = ["/cache"]
  shm_size = 0
 [runners.cache]
  [runners.cache.s3]
  [runners.cache.gcs]
```

config.toml for shell-

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "deposit-runner"
  url = "http://gitlab.mislbd.lan/"
  token = "d7ebbbaf895f2dffa3f63d5ddadb80"
  executor = "shell"
  [runners.cache]
  [runners.cache.s3]
  [runners.cache.gcs]
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message that you are seeing, "**The term 'gitlab-runner' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program**", is from Power Shell when it can't find the command that you wrote. This is usually what happens when you have not added the path of the exe file to your environment variables.

You can also write the full path to the command that you want to run in Power Shell, like this:

```
C:\dev\GitLab-Runner\glr.exe
```

I have renamed my gitlab runner file to "glr.exe", but you have to write the name of your file.

GitLab runners can be run like this and does not require docker.